# CoreData fetchRequest

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I want to make up a tableview that has 2 sections with a fetchedResultsController.

I have a data model like this :

- A Company

  - many employees
  - a employer

A Company Entity has to many relationship with Employees entity, has to one relationship with employer entity.

I was trying to use a fetchedResultsController that , and fill the cells in tableView's first section with employees, in tableView's second  section with a employer.

But failed to make up cells.

What I want is make up cells with fetchedResultsController :
   fill the employers in section 1, fill the employ in section 2.

Is it possible with fetchedResultsController?

If is it possible, how to make a keyPath for divide sections?

Or am I have to use fetchRequest, fetchRequest ?

Comment: Can you explain more about your question..?? Are you facing difficulty in fetching the core data result.?

Answer (score 1):

The indexPath that is returned from a fetchedResultsController is really useful for interoperability with a tableView or collectionView. But it does not have to be a one-to-one relationship. You can have a setup where one section points to one fetchedResultsController and another section points to a different one. The key in doing this setup is to make sure to not confuse the fetchedResultsController indexPath with your tableView's indexPath. Generally I find having a separate object to manage converting the indexPath is the easiest way to keep it straight.